# How to stop wget sequential download from including brackets in the url?

Tags: bash, wget

I'm trying to run `wget https://site.example/path/to/image/$1/{1..$2}.jpg 1 3` and it downloads files `1` to `3` from folder `1` just fine. But if I put that same script on a file, `chmod +x` it and then `./script.sh` wget tries to download `https://site.example/path/to/image/1/{1..3}.jpg` instead of downloading `https://site.example/path/to/image/1/1.jpg` `https://site.example/path/to/image/1/2.jpg`, and `https://site.example/path/to/image/1/3.jpg`. Why is that and how do I stop that behaviour? I don't get at all what I'm doing wrong. Trying to `echo 'https://site.example/path/to/image/1/{1..3}.jpg' | xargs` faces the same issue.

Comment: Using `curl -O https://site.example/path/to/image/$1/[1-$2].jpg 1 3` works flawlessly. Far from what I want but at least does the job. Guess I hate wget now.

Comment: There are two issues that can cause this: {1..$x} works in zsh but not bash, and {1..3} works in bash but not sh. Can you confirm whether `wget https://site.example/path/to/image/$1/{1..$2}.jpg 1 3` *actually* works from your shell, or whether you instead wrote `wget https://site.example/path/to/image/1/{1..3}.jpg` thinking it would be essentially the same?